# How to change settings for a Visual Studio 2005 Deployment Project

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2005

I have a project containing at least one DLL along with the executable output.  I have added a Deployment Project to this solution, which asked me for a name and working directory upon creation like all projects.

I named this "MyProduc_Installer" and have been able to modify all aspects of the installation process except for changing the name of the installer itself.  Throughout the install process, the user sees messages like "Welcome to the MyProduct_Installer Installer."  Even in the Add/Remove Programs list, this is the application's ill conceived title.

How do I change this setting?  I have tried right click/properties, as well as all the View options.  I couldn't find anything in the assembly information for the executable project, or solution properties.

I have tried right-clicking on the project in the Explorer to change the properties, but here is what I see:

[image]

There is no setting here to change the project title.

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't found the answer to this yet, here is the answer.

Visual Studio has 2 sets of properties for Projects -
1 which you can accesss by selecting the Project in Solution Explorer and then right clicking and selecting 'Properties'.

2nd set of properties is in the 'Properies' window which shows up below the Solution explorer. This is the same property window which is displayed for any of the Form property settings or any other control settings.

The 'Product Name' and other project properties for 'Setup' project can be found in the second property window.

Hope this helps.

AC

Answer (score 4):

The easy way to get to the properties you are interested in is to use the F4 shortcut when the project is highlighted.  As stated in previous posts this is a very different list to the one you get by right click and selecting properties.

Comment: The fact that this is still this hard in VS2010 is crazy, this is a great answer. I had no idea there were different property windows!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a Setup project like for winforms, it's the **ProductName** property. In Studio, I just click on the project name in the Explorer and I get the property window typical to other projects, and it's right there. Other properties include the AddRemoveProgramsIcon, InstallAllUsers, and RemovePreviousVersions.

Comment: I don't see any options like that... please see above

Answer (score 0):

I happened across this post, where I was having trouble renaming the Product as well.. In regards to using Click Once Publishing.

Since updating all the old names I couldn't get the Publishing to correct itself.
It was found notepading the project file **xyz.vbproj** in my case and updating the `<ProductName>xyz wrong name</ProductName>` element that was still wrong.

It was the only place I could find to update it, since the publishing or any property window didn't expose this.